# Material Properties-Material Preview doesnt show anything ( totally black)

Tags: texturing, materials, panel

I start to use blender for a month so i am a beginner. If its a bad question i'm sorry but i couldn't figure out the trouble.
I'm using 2.83a
In Tabs&Panes - Material Properties -the material preview doesn't show any material , its totally black for everything.
However in rendering everything is working normally.

If someone has any idea how to fix it i will be very happy.

Thanks a lot.

[image: Material Properties-Material Preview doesnt show anything ( totally black)]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Blender not loading any project material in "material preview mode" and "rendered mode", object is entirely gray as background](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/204297/blender-not-loading-any-project-material-in-material-preview-mode-and-rendere)

Answer (score 1):

it might be your graphics driver, I recently updated mine and had the same problem but when I went back to a previous version it's fixed