# AMD GPU Material in "material preview mode" and "rendered mode", is entirely gray as background. Only outline is displayed

Tags: rendering, objects, gpu

I don't know why but now, when i go in material preview or rendered (in solid mode it works fine), my object is entirely gray, or invisible idk, because it has the same color of the background.

I've been working for days on this project without having this issue, it suddenly showed up.

I tried opening other old projects and suddenly they all do the same so i guess it is some blender program setting that applies for all the projects, but idk how it happened cuz i didn't change anything :/, anyone got any tips? [image]

Comment: Are you using an AMD GPU with driver version >20.11.1?

Comment: Yeah, i just realized that since the problem has appeared, the only thing i changed is that i updated the amd drivers, i also just read a discussion that says that it is the problem. :/

Comment: What if you're not using an AMD driver and still getting the same problem?

Answer (score 13):

**Update:** Blender 2.92.0, 2.91.1 and 2.83.11 will contain workarounds for the missing / incorrectly rendered surfaces of mesh, curves and metaballs as well as the incorrectly rendered wireframes caused by bugs in the graphics driver.

---

The graphics driver version Adrenalin 2020 Edition 20.11.2 and later appear to cause issues for several users, as reported in [T82856](https://developer.blender.org/T82856) and related tickets. Installing a previous driver version should solve these problems until the bug in the driver is fixed or Blender provides a workaround for the problem.

Comment: Adrenalin 2020 Edition 20.9.2 fixed this issue for me

Comment: Blender 2.83.11 and 2.91.1 will also have these work around so added.

Comment: @J.Bakker Thanks. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 11):

As mentioned in the bug report [T82856](https://developer.blender.org/T82856) a temporary solution is to enable **High Quality Normals** under the Performance section in the Rendering tab on the right in a default Blender layout.

[image: Rendering tab]

Answer (score 2):

**Just roll back to the previous version of your AMD driver.**
Click on the windows icon
Search for **Device Manager**
Dropdown the **Display Adapters** option
click on AMD driver
Under the Driver's Tab
**Roll Back Driver** Option
And now the Blender is good again.

Comment: What if you don't have an AMD driver and still getting the same problem? I'm using NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 6GB

Answer (score 2):

Blender Version 2.91.2 addresses some of the problems with AMD cards

https://developer.blender.org/T83216