# Everything is transparent (Eevee)

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

So all of a sudden somehow  everything ends up transparent, just like in the attached images. I honestly have no clue why this started happening or how to prevent it, so I'm hoping someone could help?

Viewport: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXbYl.jpg

Render: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPLtA.jpg

Comment: if you have an AMD graphic card it may be because of the last driver

Comment: I tried in three different versions of Blender, same result. Dunno what's up

Comment: The issue is most likely caused by your graphics card driver, see [AMD GPU Material in "material preview mode" and "rendered mode", is entirely gray as background. Only outline is displayed](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/204297/amd-gpu-material-in-material-preview-mode-and-rendered-mode-is-entirely-gra)

Comment: Please **use the tools from this site 
to upload images** so that they are displayed as part of your question. 
See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)