# File will not render in recent versions

Tags: rendering

[image]I have files of earlier versions that render when I try it, but my most recent version will not and I can't seem to figure out why. When I press the render shortcut it populates the window but seems to instantly finish (sort of like it isn't trying to execute) but can't find the data. I am using a Radeon RX 580 graphics card, using  Cycles as my render engine, and have the 2.90.1 version of Blender.

[enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1C7b_nHR4YVcVsj1oZEOSUFnyu_WmbUyn/view?usp=sharing)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, instead of a link to your file, please add a screenshot. By any chance if you have an AMD graphics card it is most certainly due to a faulty driver. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/204297/amd-gpu-material-in-material-preview-mode-and-rendered-mode-is-entirely-gra

Comment: Hi and welcome. Please [edit] your question and add images of your interface. Are using cycles or EEVEE? Rendering a still or animation? What version of blender are you using? Please add more to your question than a link to a file. Thanks :)

Comment: The drivers for AMD cards have a lot of reports of problems. Update or downgrade the drivers.

Comment: @Gorgious - Sorry, I updated the post some and will definitely look into there being any issues with the drivers.

Comment: @Timaroberts - Hey, yeah I wasn't even sure what to include in the post. Thanks for the feedback and quick response!

Comment: @susu - Thanks! Hopefully that'll fix it!