# Can't shade or color my sculpt

Tags: sculpting, color

I'm new to sculpting, and after sculpting some alien-y kinda abyssal, I'm trying to color it. However, when I change to the shading viewport, it goes kinda transparent, and when I go to the shading tab it freaks out completely. Here's some screenshots (or pictures from my phone, in this case)

[image: this is my sculpt]

[image: this is how it shows immediately after I click on the shading tab]

[image: this is what happens when I rotate the mesh]

[image: another one for a better description]

Comment: You need to clean your keyboard.... To make screenshots in blender use WIndow> Save Screenshot. Photos of the screen are hard to read.

Comment: @susu I usually clean up every morning, but it's super windy and super dusty here. Anyway, thanks for the tips, screenshots added.

Comment: seems like graphic card issue ??? Does it happen with difault Cube too? BTW to be able add material you have to select the object.

Comment: Try updating/downgrading the drivers for the graphics card:  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/204297/amd-gpu-material-in-material-preview-mode-and-rendered-mode-is-entirely-gra

Answer (score 1):

In the screen shots you sent it shows you in "Object Mode", you can't paint or sculpt in this mode.

[image]

To paint textures you have to go to "Texture Paint", and have the proper setup to paint.

To sculpt you have to go into "Sculpt mode", and a object you can sculpt with

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So, at first I thought the issue was with my poly count, even though my computerwas able to render heavier objects before.

After fiddling with the render engines and changing it from cycles, to workbench, then to eevee multiple times, it decided to work.

I don't know if I should just delete the question or leave it here in case someone has a similar issue, so I'm leaving it unless a mod decides to delete it.

Comment: It is a common Radeon issue right now.  See susu's previous link.