# Evee Not Working

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

[image: This is what happens when rendered mode in Evee]

[image: Lighting and shading is not working]

My specs-
Blender 2.91
intel i5-9400f
AMD Radeon RX 570
driver version - 20.11.2
RAM - 16 GB
Windows 10 64 bit

Comment: It's probably a problem with the latest AMD driver, switch back to a previous one, or try Properties panel > Render > Performance > High Quality Normals

Comment: Better thank  moonboots... he  may be onto something there. Here is a similar question  [AMD GPU Material in "material preview mode" and "rendered mode", is entirely gray as background. Only outline is displayed](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/204297/amd-gpu-material-in-material-preview-mode-and-rendered-mode-is-entirely-gra)  which may answer your question. . It has been marked  as a dupe of around 20 or more very similar questions in the last week or two.  I have voted to close this question on grounds that it too is a duplicate