# Why is this happening with blender now?

Tags: modeling

Blender 2.81 screen upon loading

[image]

so, all of a sudden i'm having issues now with blender. i uninstalled and reinstalled blender 2.81 and 2.9, and they are both having the same issue upon initial loading. NONE of the preferances has been changed or anything. this is a picture of the stock cube that is given everytime. and as you can see in the screenshot, the viewport shading is set on wireframe, so i should be able to see it all, but i don't. i've checked all the settings and everything and nothing helps. i installed it on a seperate computer, on the off chance that it was my desktop going bad, but alas, on my laptop it is having the very same issue, new install and everything. if anyone else is having this problem and has fixed it, please let me know!!! i am in the middle of developing a video game and now i can't use blender to 3d model anything anymore.

Comment: AMD GPU by any chance?

Comment: yes, actually. working on getting a new gpu. currently i have the radeon 570rx

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/204297/amd-gpu-material-in-material-preview-mode-and-rendered-mode-is-entirely-gra

Comment: but the problem also persists on my laptop, which has an AMD Radeon HD 7650M, driver version 15.20.. and blender was working.. now it's not. i even tried installing older versions, and still nothing

Comment: and also, blender 2.81 does not have the high quality normals option as displayed in the answer provided above

Comment: 2.90 does, but still doesnt solve the issue of when i put it into wireframe mode, i still just get the outline as seen in the screenshot i provided in my initial question.

Comment: ok, i DID in fact read that part, but that would only solve the issue for my pc, and not the laptop, as the amd driver on my laptop has not been updated in a couple years, and blender has been working on it fine till recently. i'm no NOOB, but also understand that there may be more to the issue than a simple driver problem. if that was the case, it would be working fine on my laptop. but the current driver for my laptop was from back in 2015, and have had absolutely NO issues at all till now.