# I get a weird visual glitch when using the shading tab on Blender. How can I solve this?

Tags: materials, shaders, error, gpu

The Shading preview stoped showing what it should. Instead it shows a weird reflexion of the background as you can see in the following pictures:

The first one shows the model using the solid preview

[image: foosbal table model]

The second one shows what it looks like when I try to see the material preview

[image: Material Preview]

The third one shows what i see when I move the camera a little (pressing the middle mouse button and dragging)

[image: Material Preview when I move the camera]

This issue is not exclusive to this project, but happens on every other project too. This also happens if I open a new project that only contains a cube. I have let a friend of mine run the foosball model and it worked on his computer, so it has to be a problem with my PC or any blender files on my PC. It used to work on it perfectly, but after some time, it didn't anymore.

I've tried the following:
Uninstalled Blender.
Cleaned temporary and registry files with CCleaner
Updated my graphics card's software to the newest version (AMD Radeon R9 380X, version 20.12.1)
Restarted my PC
Reinstalled Blender.

It didn't solve the problem. Can anyone help me out?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is this your problem? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/204297/amd-gpu-material-in-material-preview-mode-and-rendered-mode-is-entirely-gra

Answer (score 0):

You could try to go into to edit mode and recalculate the normals by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>.