# Blender wireframe & cycles acting wierd

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, 3d-view

**Backstory**

I have a Radeon RX 570 and decided to try out Blender and 3D modelling in general. But after about 2 months I started getting some strange graphical bugs. I did manage to fix a couple of them but apparently blender doesn't like AMD Users. Then I got the wireframe issue.

**Problem**

Wireframe viewpoint comes up with this now  and I have yet to fix it. Also for Cycles, It can't even render on the viewpoint and if I dare to render it as an image, my whole PC freezes up.

[image]
**What I've tried**
For the wireframe viewpoint strangely breaking I've tried...

- Reinstalling Blender to an older version
- Reinstalling Blender and install a portable install
- Going through each setting
- Updated any possible driver and software

For Cycles I've tried...

- Changing Cycles rendering device to each possible selection
- Reinstalling Blender again

Each solution I've tried hasn't fixed anything

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/204297/amd-gpu-material-in-material-preview-mode-and-rendered-mode-is-entirely-gra

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your post 
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and use the tools from this site 
to upload images so that they are displayed as part of your question. 
See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)