# Material preview not working, just shows glitch moveable look texture

Tags: uv

What ever I go to the material viewer my texture doesn't show but instead shows grey out texture.
Also what ever I move the view the grey texture just moves outside the model.

Are there some ways I could fix that?

[image]

Comment: Looks like this:
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/204297/amd-gpu-material-in-material-preview-mode-and-rendered-mode-is-entirely-gra?noredirect=1&lq=1