# Render doesent show almost anything (material or textures)

Tags: rendering, texturing, 3d-view

a little while ago was everything working perfectly. But now, when i have even just basic cube in the scene, then when i want to add texture or materieal, or even if i wont add any of them to the cube, when i go to Rendered viewport shading, all i see is this (just a grey cube with nothing on it, i have set the color tu blue but nothing):

[image: Viewport shading render doesent work for me now]

And when i render it it shows just checkered cube like this:

[image: Checkered cube]

I know its probably gonna be something dumb, but i just cant figure out what the problem is. Thanks for help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AMD GPU Material in "material preview mode" and "rendered mode", is entirely gray as background. Only outline is displayed](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/204297/amd-gpu-material-in-material-preview-mode-and-rendered-mode-is-entirely-gra)   Similar  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/204297?sort=newest

Comment: Thats it, that helped, thank you