# 2.91 Render Viewport.. Bugging out?

Tags: 3d-view

On eevee engine, has anyone experienced the same?
[image: Render Viewport]

It looks normal on Solid Viewport. This also happened in 2.82, but it was worse. Solid is basically transparent, while render is basically the same as current version, hence why i updated my blender.

[image: Solid Viewport]

My rig if anyone needs it : Ryzen 3 3200G, 16Gig RAM, RX 480 4GB. I swear it never runs anything else with a problem. Blender was working fine a few days ago too. Cycles works on render viewport, but material preview still bugged out.

Comment: rig if anyone needs it :
Ryzen 3 3200G, 16Gig RAM, RX 480 4GB. I swear it never run anything else with a problem. Blender was working fine a few days ago too.

Comment: please add any and all new information to the body of your question as an [edit]. This is not a forum with a continual running dialogue.

Comment: GPUs from AMD have been having a lot of problems lately with the "upgraded" drivers, try downgrading the drivers to an older Read: version.https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/204297/amd-gpu-material-in-material-preview-mode-and-rendered-mode-is-entirely-gra

Comment: I see, that link really helps a lot! Enabling "High Quality Normals" fixed it. Maybe i'll downgrade my driver too if the problem persists. Thank you very much everyone!