# Eevee rendering issue

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine

I am experiencing a strange rendering/viewport issue with Eevee that I can't seem to find any other posts about anywhere. Here's 2 screenshots, the first one is of a cycles viewport of a scene, and the second is of an eevee viewport of the same scene.

The Cycles screenshot:
[image]

The Eevee screenshot:

[image]

Keep in mind these two screenshots are from the exact same blend file and the only difference between the two images is the engine.

Thanks for any and all help.

Comment: looks like yet another AMD driver issue. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/204297/amd-gpu-material-in-material-preview-mode-and-rendered-mode-is-entirely-gra

Comment: try switching screen space reflections in the eevee render engine settings , it not bieng up used to cause wierd things with me