# My friend can't see the textures of my mdoel in the viewport while using eevee

Tags: texturing, uv

I have packed the textures into de .blend file, but when he opens the file he can't see the textures on the model (If he switches to cycles then he can, but I can see the textures in both eevee and cycles).

my specs: AMD Ryzen 5 2400g, 4096MB ATI Radeon RX 570 Series.
My friend's specs: AMD Ryzen 5 2400g, Radeon 580 8gb.

we're both on ver 2.9 of blender

I will post pictures of both what my friend sees vs the model.

[image: this is what I see]

[image: second image is what my friend sees]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AMD GPU Material in "material preview mode" and "rendered mode", is entirely gray as background. Only outline is displayed](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/204297/amd-gpu-material-in-material-preview-mode-and-rendered-mode-is-entirely-gra)  Others recently closed with this issue https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/204297?sort=active

Comment: Can he see textures on other models in eevee?