# When I duplicate the block I am duplicating disappeares

Tags: interface

When I duplicate the item once it  is still there, then when I duplicate again it disappears but still shows the outline of the box where it should be when that area is clicked on [image]

Comment: Hello, please share a screenshot.

Comment: Hi, hopefully that shows you what I mean, the yellow box is my original, but disappeares after I duplicate a second time

Comment: Also, very important: [**how to take _real_ screenshots**](https://www.take-a-screenshot.org/windows.html)

Comment: Do you have an AMD Graphics Card ? If so see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/204297/amd-gpu-material-in-material-preview-mode-and-rendered-mode-is-entirely-gra

Comment: Thanks for your help ☺️ I do have a AMD card and that link solved my problem