# When I go to render my animation, I get a glitched square group of pixels

Tags: cycles-render-engine, glass

[image: rendered image]Im thinking the glass material is causing these artifacts but I'm not sure and I don't know where to begin to fix.  Please assist.  I've provided a link to my blend file.

Also a note,
It looks great all the way until the very last second of the rendering.  I've tried increasing my sample size and light paths.
blend file
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ijLczaE_jHWRV4IM7a37v1aZ0QI5S1pZ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi there. 500+ MB is a rather large file-size to ask users to download to preview. Could you perhaps create a copy of your scene and remove all objects that are not relevant to the problem? - it will bring the file size down, and you may just stumble on to your problem along the way (sometimes you'll delete something that ended up being the problem in the first place, or find a hidden object you forgot about or something like that)

Comment: Obligatory visit if you happen to have an AMD graphics card >> https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/204297/amd-gpu-material-in-material-preview-mode-and-rendered-mode-is-entirely-gra