# Material preview doesn't show color changes, the object stays black

Tags: edit-mode, color

I've just started a Blender course, but I got an issue. When I go to the Material Preview and want to change the color, nothing happens, it stays black.

http://kepkezelo.com/images/lupyilfvfg4qb6hwq4vt.png

Comment: This is probably because of your AMD driver, switch to the previous or try Properties panel > Render > Performance > High Quality Normals

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AMD GPU Material in "material preview mode" and "rendered mode", is entirely gray as background. Only outline is displayed](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/204297/amd-gpu-material-in-material-preview-mode-and-rendered-mode-is-entirely-gra)   Other recently asked questions displaying same issue https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/204297?sort=active