# Color not changing in eevee in material view

Tags: color

I am using a course from Udemy that says to change the color of the selected object, you should:

- be in Object Mode
- Render engine set to Eevee
- View set to Rendered

I have done this, but when I choose 'Material', and try and pick a color on the color pinwheel, the object does not change.  I have tried Edit mode, View set to material, nothing appears to work.  Why is this simple task so complicated? :(

Comment: please [edit] your question and add an image that shows the problem. Additionally, are you using a GPU by the brand AMD? There have been a lot of problems with the drivers fur such hardware lately.

Comment: See [How to upload an image 
to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AMD GPU Material in "material preview mode" and "rendered mode", is entirely gray as background. Only outline is displayed](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/204297/amd-gpu-material-in-material-preview-mode-and-rendered-mode-is-entirely-gra)   Other questions related to issue https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/204297?sort=active  this one is a good match https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/208172/material-preview-doesnt-show-color-changes-the-object-stays-black