# My model is not showing correctly in the viewport

Tags: modeling, rendering, materials, 3d-view, light

I´ve been working on this model for some time now, i added some materials and added light, it had been working just fine , until i loaded the project today and my model is now like this...

Thanks for the attention.  [image]

Comment: Are you using a GPU by AMD? Check this post:  [amd-gpu-material-in-material-preview-mode-and-rendered-mode-is-entirely-gray](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/204297/amd-gpu-material-in-material-preview-mode-and-rendered-mode-is-entirely-gra)