# Why is it when I render I Get a blank grey screen

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I've been having this problem, and I don't know why. ill just give some context. I had imported this model from SketchUp, along with the camera view from there. It was working fine, until I decided to delete the SketchUp cam, and decided to add a new one. I've been having problems since I added the new cam. The model is just fine, and so are the materials, When I put the viewport shading into any mode the model looks fine, however when I decide to render all I get is a grey screen when it finishes rendering. I'm using the cycles render engine. I have read all of the other forums that are similar to mine. I have checked that its not an issue of clipping, or depth of field, or that it is a material problem. I just seem to be stuck. Would be great if someone can shed some light on what I'm doing wrong

Many thanks in advance

Comment: provide your blend file

Comment: We'll need some details to solve your issue.  A screenshot of the gray screen (there are a couple different things that could be described as a "gray screen") and the viewport render are a good way to start.

Comment: Maybe it's a hardware problem like in this post, we had a lot of those questions here:
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/204297/amd-gpu-material-in-material-preview-mode-and-rendered-mode-is-entirely-gra

Answer (score 0):

The new camera you added may somehow be set as an inactive camera. This is the case if the triangle over the camera is an outline and not solid. Select the camera, go to the view menu, go to cameras, and click “set active object as camera.“