# I can't see objects created in Blender unless I select them

Tags: objects

Am brand new to Blender. When I watch tutorials I see you open the program and see a default cube which is a light gray. However, when I open it, I don't see it in light gray but rather in an orange outline. If I deselect my cube it then becomes invisible. I tried to see if it was a setting or something but after much searching and asking, I am starting to suspect it is either a bug or a graphics card issue or something else? Not sure! I apologize if there is a simple fix and I am just new. I've tried everything I can think of.

I have:

- Windows 10
- AMD FIrepro V5900 graphics card (a little over 5 GB I believe?)
- Blender version 2.8 (I had to download this from a non-Blender site, as when I try to click on "Download 2.8" on Blender it automatically redirects me to 2.92. I can't use that version, it crashes before it will even open. I already figured out this is because I don't have a graphics card that works with it apparently...so I heard getting an older version would work better).

I've tried:

- fiddling with viewport shading settings.
- rolling back my driver (apparently I can't do this - my computer had it as an option but it was greyed-out, I don't know if this means my driver is already at it's oldest version? I actually checked it was updated to the latest driver back when I was trying to install 2.92)

[image: There is a cube here but since it's not selected you can't see it. THat's what I mean by it being "invisible"]

Comment: there's a problem with the latest AMD driver, maybe try to switch to a previous one or try Properties panel > Render > Performance > High Quality Normals: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/204297/amd-gpu-material-in-material-preview-mode-and-rendered-mode-is-entirely-gra

Comment: You can download any previous official Blender version [here](https://download.blender.org/release/).

Comment: Thanks for responding! I had downloaded v 2.7 and gotten it to work. Then when you mentioned the Properties panel thing I decided to try it but had already uninstalled 2.8 I managed to find a version from the Blender site to download (it was kind of hidden!) and once I reinstalled everything seems to be working properly now! I feel like a big dope, but maybe this post can help anyone else in the future?