# Why does object in viewport shading render view suddenly disappear

Tags: rendering, shader-nodes

When I switch from viewport shading solid to viewport shading render suddenly every objects disappears. Just a second before everything was perfect in render view. In just a matter of time when I came back to viewport shading render from viewport shading solid the screen got fully greyed out. I also checked several other options such as objects visibility(eye icon in right) and objects that are hidden by pressing     alt + H and / key if anything is isolated. I am using blender version 2.92.100. Could someone help me out with this coz I am stuck with this.[image]

Comment: Do you have an AMD graphics card ?

Comment: i don't see any lighting in your scene...but since this is just a screenshot...it would help if you provide your blend file.

Comment: No I have NVIDIA RTX 2060

Answer (score 1):

I suppose Gorgious might be correct with his guess. If you have an AMD graphics card you might have a look at this question:

[AMD GPU material is entirely gray](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/204297/amd-gpu-material-in-material-preview-mode-and-rendered-mode-is-entirely-gra)

Since you have *Overlays* disabled, there will not even be an outline of selected objects visible etc.

If it's not the graphics card, check if you might have disabled the *Object Types Visibility* for *Mesh* by accident (see left side of screenshot). Or maybe you have disabled the *Ray Visibility* for *Camera* in the *Object Properties* (right side of screenshot), but the latter you must have done on each object that's in the scene which I doubt.

If it's none of the above providing a blend file would be better to find out what it might be. Even if there would be no light in the scene, the world background shines a dim light on the objects so there must at least be *something* visible. Or do all objects have only a Diffuse shader set completely to white maybe?

[image: visibility settings]

Comment: Downvoted? This might not be solution, but I don't think (quoting from the help pages) "the post contains wrong information, is poorly researched, or fails to communicate information". As long as there isn't more information in the question or a blend file there isn't much more to guess...

Comment: +1 I think guesses are great, because even if they don't help the OP, they might help a visitor from Google.

Comment: i agree! +1 for u, he probably downvoted coz he didnt have AMD xd

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie Yeah, might be - if I had known that by the time I wrote the answer... but my answer actually deals with other things apart from having AMD GPUs.

Answer (score 0):

In the *3d Viewport* click on menu *View  > View Regions > Clipping Region* or use shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to solve the issue