# unable to render properly

Tags: rendering

This Question is same as
[AMD GPU Material in "material preview mode" and "rendered mode", is entirely gray as background. Only outline is displayed](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/204297/amd-gpu-material-in-material-preview-mode-and-rendered-mode-is-entirely-gra)

I am using Blender 2.93 and was learning blender with Doughnut tutorial of blender guru. When I came to the part of rendering the object was unable to render. I even tried it with just the default general cube object which comes up when opening a new file. The render during both times was like in the image.

[image: Render Of the default cube]

Comment: That definitely looks like some kind of GPU or OpenGL error. First thing I would do is make sure your GPU is supported (docs on supported GPU"s here - https://code.blender.org/2019/04/supported-gpus-in-blender-2-80/  ) and that your drivers are up to date.

Comment: what are your system specs: OS/CPU/GPU?

Comment: I am using a laptop
OS:- Windows 10 Home
CPU:-  I5 8th gen
GPU 1 :- Radeon 530 (2 GB RAM)
GPU 2 :- Intel UHD 620 (1 GB RAM)

Answer (score 0):

Well it was a system problem, I kinda fixed it by changing the rendering engine to Cycles, and then selecting GPU Compute as Device.