# Blender Display in material and Display render preview bug

Tags: rendering, materials

Since a few weeks I have a problem with Blender. When I want to have a look at my final version or render it, I can't see anything. It's extremly hard to explain that's why I made a short video. I reinstalled Blender about 2-3 times but it never worked. I hope I can find help here :)

Video:
https://youtu.be/v76i1OTpoqQ

Renderd Picture:
[image]

Comment: Looks like the well-known AMD GPU driver issue. Have you updated the drivers recently? If so, try going back to an earlier version. See [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/204297/amd-gpu-material-in-material-preview-mode-and-rendered-mode-is-entirely-gra) posting.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it out