# Blender glitching

Tags: mesh, 3d-view

Ok so whenever i import a mesh or i add a mesh into blender, the mesh just looks strange, here take a look:

[image]

yes i have AMD GPU.

Comment: Any chance you have an AMD GPU?

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/204297/amd-gpu-material-in-material-preview-mode-and-rendered-mode-is-entirely-gra  and Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/204297