# I'm getting this lighting problem only on eevee, these are default settings and it happens on every save file

Tags: eevee-render-engine, lighting

[image]
I've tried turning up max distance in cascaded shadow map, I have both scene lights and scene world ticked. Material for the cube and the plane is both default Principled BSDF.. If I had to guess, it was some sort of shortcut that I accidentally fat-fingered. Material for the cube and the plane is both default Principled BSDF.

Comment: can u provide blend file?

Comment: @Chris [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=dV5eePo8" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/dV5eePo8/) its a different files but the settings are all the same

Comment: your uploaded file show me this: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Aw6m.jpg was this intended?

Comment: Do you have an AMD GPU? It looks similar to the AMD GPU driver bug: [AMD GPU Material in "material preview mode" and "rendered mode", is entirely gray as background. Only outline is displayed](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/204297/amd-gpu-material-in-material-preview-mode-and-rendered-mode-is-entirely-gra/204303#204303)

Comment: yes i didnt intend to use that file, but the lighting issue is consistent across all my new files, with that one being the first one where it occured, and i dont have a gpu, im using cpu rendering unfortunately