# a .OBJ model can't be seen, is this a bug or what?

Tags: rendering, obj

so i import a model that downloaded from a website, the weird thing is, it loads perfectly, i can see it on solid mode and texture paint but cannot be seen on Rendered mode. what is happening?

[image: Rendered View Mode]

[image: Solid View Mode]

Comment: can you show as more informations? render engine, material settings, render settings? It may have alpha set to 0

Comment: it's on Eevee, for the material settings and render settings, it's on default. i'm new on blender

Comment: AMD gpu? See: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/204297/amd-gpu-material-in-material-preview-mode-and-rendered-mode-is-entirely-gra

Comment: @brockmann is it good if i just update the blender to latest version instead?

Comment: try from easiest to hardest, try to look at settings of that object, if it is not object, try different object, is it same or not? If it is still bad, try to reinstall blender or use other versions, still nothing good? try drivers