# can someone help me with that weird glitch?

Tags: rendering, mesh, objects, 3d-view, lighting

so i have been using blender since 2019, and i did stop working on it for a while, but when i came back to work again this glitch thing appeared. i did update it but nothing change, and i did deleted it and reinstall it and it's the same problem.
[image]

Comment: Could you please specify the problem that you are facing

Comment: Are you using an AMD graphics card and has the driver been updated since you last used Blender? If so, see [this posting](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/204297/amd-gpu-material-in-material-preview-mode-and-rendered-mode-is-entirely-gra) although the effect is slightly different in your case.

Comment: if you notice, there is a glitch texture on the mesh and even when i put a texture, it wont change. and when i render it, the glitch disappear but the object or the mesh is entirely gray.

Comment: @JohnEason yes! thanks!