# Why is Shader Editor doing this?

Tags: shaders, settings

when I see people enter the Shader Editor in the tutorials I see, the default cube (or any mesh for that matter) is a solid white color from every angle. However, my default meshes in the Shader Editor are not a solid color, instead initially appearing a dark grey color, but viewing from a different angle seems to cause it to become the color of the background and creates this strange effect. This also seems to prevent me from using the erase alpha option in Vertex Paint. How can I fix this issue so meshes are solid white again? The meshes are solid white in Object View, but not in the Shader Editor. [image]

Comment: It's hard to find a single solution to that. It could possibly be a number of stuff. Could you share your blend file? (i hope it's not heavy)

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be succinct, unique and identifying, and summarize what the issue is so that users can at a glance broadly understand what your post is about before opening it. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid any emojis salutations or extraneous text not essential to the question. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and will weight heavily on their decision to open your question, which will directly affect the number of answers you might get.

Comment: Hello, it was not a blend file necessarily. I am only using the default scene, and I am using the brand new 3.0 version with default settings.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using the latest 3.0 version too, but nothing seems to be out of place. Hence the request for the blend file, even though i do understand that it's probably not something that happened through a usage fault

Comment: Do you have an AMD GPU? If so, try enabling _High Quality Normals_ under _Render Properties > Performance_. If that doesn't work, try updating your graphics drivers (or downgrading in some cases) - see here - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/204297/amd-gpu-material-in-material-preview-mode-and-rendered-mode-is-entirely-gra.

Comment: Thank you, I will try High Quality Normals and see if that helps.

Comment: Update: Thank you Christopher Bennett, that was the issue! High Quality Normals solved my problem. Thank you to everyone who helped me.