# skin textures not rendering from a premade image

Tags: rendering

So, disclaimer, I'm about six hours in to learning Blender. I've gotten to a point where I can mostly create and render a rough scene in a way that will work for me (I'm using Blender for perspective references to then use in photoshop).
Problem is that I got an image from CGtrader and I can't get it to render right. It's [this image](https://www.cgtrader.com/3d-models/character/woman/sexy-bikini-woman-2d1e6999-46a4-4b3a-ac12-2d41db67482d)

Downloaded it, extracted it, opened the .blend and I can't find any way to get the skin to display correctly. It either renders all in black in Eevee and Cycles (clothing renders correctly) or in greyscale in workbench.

[image] cycles

[image] eevee

[image] screenshot of when I open the .blend

Any suggestions? I feel like there's something very obvious I'm missing but I can't find a solution anywhere. Thanks a bunch!!

ps. I'm using Linux Mint if that makes a difference

Comment: A screenshot of the skin material in the _Shader Editor_ would be interesting to see how the material is setup... and the _UV Editor_ to see how the UV map looks. When I look at the model site, I see it's a native Blender model - so I would expect it to be correct right from the start. Usually those problems are more common when objects are non-native file formats... hard to tell without the file what the problem is.

Comment: Or maybe it's a graphic card / driver issue like in this question: [AMD GPU Material is entirely gray](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/204297/) but the resulting error looks different than yours...