# Basic cube not moving - only outline moves

Tags: axis

I got stuck using basic blender - I was learning from this tutorial [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyc8O.gif)

However, I'm having a problem where the cube isn't moving anymore, only the outline moves:

[image: MoveNo1]

I have checked and "Affect Only" checkboxes are un-checked:

[image: MoveNo2]

I also don't think it's a GPU issue because it was working before - something has changed.

Here is some more strange behavior. Anyone know what could be causing this?

[image: MoveNo3]

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: newbies are not allowed to insret images sir + It was 2.10MB so system was not allowing to upload.

Comment: Is this the issue? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/204297/amd-gpu-material-in-material-preview-mode-and-rendered-mode-is-entirely-gra

Comment: No, not that one. Previously it was woking something seems to have changed.

Comment: Origin/locations/parents: All are unchecked. [img](https://ibb.co/DRn6Tpn)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide more info or provide a blend file that shows the issue.  Your question will be automatically queued for review to be reopened.

Comment: I went ahead and did the edit - someone help me re-open, becausecause I _have_ to know what the problem is - I've been messing around trying to re-create for _far_ too long, to no avail ;)

Comment: I am 99% sure this is a a hardware issue. It could be working one day and not the other for a variety of reasons. Drivers, OS update, a change in blender source code...

Comment: I tried 2.83 version → same issue. I now downloaded 2.8 versions it is working fine so far.

Comment: i think its the problem of only the basic block . i had the same problem but i can move the duplicate of it. i press tab a couple times and glitched the cube. and i could move the basic block .it only works sometimes though.