# Why Is Wireframe Shading Only Showing Object Outline

Tags: wireframe

I'm following a tutorial on Skillshare where the instructor switches to Wireframe Shading by pressing 'Z + Wireframe':

[image]

Unfortunately when I try to replicate this on my Mac, it's only giving me an outline of the shape, and doesn't show the 16 (?) lines within it:

[image]

Why is that the case? I've checked 'High Quality Normals' under Performance just as an answer to [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/204297/amd-gpu-material-in-material-preview-mode-and-rendered-mode-is-entirely-gra) suggests. And I'm using Blender version 2.93.5 so I don't think it should have anything to do with outdated versions. Any other ideas? Just want to follow along as best as possible.

Comment: Which icons do you have hilighted at the top of your Subdiv Surface modifier and are the other settings on the modifier panel the same as in the tutorial image? - He's using Blender 2.81, but 2.93 should give the same result.

Comment: @JohnEason when switching over to the Subdiv Surface modifier panel it looks like all of my settings are [exactly the same as his](https://i.imgur.com/lt0o4Pn.jpg)

Comment: nope, you didn't check the most left button

Comment: As @chris says, there is one crucial difference between your settings and those of the tutor. You have 'Optimal Display' checked whereas the tutor does not! Uncheck yours and all will be revealed!

Comment: @JohnEason Yeah that was it. Unchecking 'Optimal Display' did the trick. Thank you.

Comment: If you're following a tutorial always check whether the version you are using is the same as that of the tutorial and if it's different take particular care to check that all settings are the same. For instance in 2.8x the order of the row of icons in the modifier is different to 2.93. The other main difference between versions is how you actually apply the modifier. 2.8x has Apply and Copy buttons whereas those options are on a dropdown at the end of the row of icons in 2.93 and above.