# Blender 2.8 Viewport Glitching out

Tags: 3d-view

I recently downloaded Blender 2.82a and I've been having some issues with the viewport. I have tried other versions of Blender, such as 2.79 and 3.0 and this issue doesn't happen on other versions. Whenever I go on material view, the model does this weird thing when I move the camera and it also doesn't show the material applied to it.[image: glitched cube material view]

After I go on material view and go back to the solid view or wireframe view it looks like this. [image: glitched cube solid view]

It happens on both Eevee and Cycles and my graphic drivers are up to date with the latest version. If anyone can help with this problem feel free to help!

Comment: This is a problem very commonly associated with AMD GPU's and drivers - updating to the latest version doesn't always fix it - this was a huge problem around Jan 2021 with some bad drivers that caused many users to need to actually revert to an earlier driver version to fix it. _HOWEVER_, many people have also had success (and doged the driver problem) by enabling _High Quality Normals_ under `Render Properties > Performance`. See here - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/204297/amd-gpu-material-in-material-preview-mode-and-rendered-mode-is-entirely-gra

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the quick response! I'll try this out

Comment: Oh, there's a problem though. I don't know if its normal but blender doesnt have the performance property in the render properties tab. I'll try downloading a newer version, Thanks for your help though!

Comment: Yeah. You said you were using 2.82a - isn't that an alpha build anyway? That's probably the source of your problem.

Comment: Yep. Thing is it happened with 2.8 and 2.83 too, but updating fixed the problem.