# Materials cannot be seen in Blender 3D Viewpoint

Tags: materials, shaders

my problem is hard to describe so here's a record of it: https://youtu.be/yOaqwZkTl0Q Basically when I go into the shading tab the object is sort of invisible with a delay, as when I move around it takes the color of the background...  The cube is just the default cube, so this is just an empty project, thou the same happens with projects I made previously, when my Blender was working, even with bought shaders

The problem arises only when I use any shader. If I put e.g. the Color ramp directly into the material output without any shader I get the cube green.

I work with materials very rarely, so maybe its something really simple or stupid, but via google I couldn't find this exact problem. And as far as I remember it should not behave like that? Like when I set basecolor green I expect the cube to get green. In tutorial videos it works that way at least. Render Engine is Eevee, Blender version 2.90.0. Thanks for your help

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/204297/amd-gpu-material-in-material-preview-mode-and-rendered-mode-is-entirely-gra

Comment: Ah, perfect, Thank you very much!