# My Mesh won't move on Solid View or Material Preview

Tags: objects

So, when I try to move, rotate or scale the mesh, only the center point moves, it affects in the rendered view, but not on the solid or material preview. I already checked, Transform Affects Only is not avtivated to affect only origins, locations or parents. What could be the problem? Could it be a weak hardware?

[image]

Comment: Please share your blend file via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to add the link to your question.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/204297/amd-gpu-material-in-material-preview-mode-and-rendered-mode-is-entirely-gra